# Is by a reserved keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reserved-words

I can't find "by" in lists of reserved keywords in C# but the Resharper Visual Studio plug-in seems to consider it being one - it prepends it with a @ escape whenever it generates code (e.g. by executing a refactoring command)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**by**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713645.aspx) is a [Query Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx), i.e., it's a keyword only in certain positions within [LINQ Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx), in particular only within a [**group** clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx).

> The **by** contextual keyword is used in the **group** clause in a query expression to specify how the returned items should be grouped.

Comment: I wonder why `by` is not mentioned as a _contextual keyword_ on the page [C# Keywords (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) when for example the words `select`, `group`, `orderby`, and `descending` are on that list?

Comment: MSDN groups all keywords into categories ([Statement Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt4z8b0f.aspx), [Namespace Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxtk6h5e.aspx), and so on). Although `by` *is* a Contextual Keyword, it seems the MSDN folks felt that grouping all [Query Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx) into a category separate from the [Contextual Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx) improves the usability of the documentation. I'm not sure why the Keywords overview page doesn't list all Query Keywords.

Comment: The C# Language Specification has this: _Query expressions contain a number of “contextual keywords”, i.e., identifiers that have special meaning in a given context. Specifically these are `from`, `where`, `join`, `on`, `equals`, `into`, `let`, `orderby`, `ascending`, `descending`, `select`, `group` and `by`. In order to avoid ambiguities in query expressions caused by mixed use of these identifiers as keywords or simple names, these identifiers are considered keywords when occurring anywhere within a query expression. [...]_

Comment: Interestingly all the query keywords are included in the contextual list except for `in`, `on`, `equals` and `by`. Intriguing overlap.

Comment: @MarcGravell Of those, `in` is the only one which is _also_ a "full" (non-contextual) keyword.

Comment: I'd guess people are more likely to look for `from` instead of `in`, `join` instead of `on` and `equals`, and `group` instead of `by`.

Answer (score 5):

`by` is used within LINQ query syntax. It's reserved only within [query syntax context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

`by` is not a reserved word it is a `query word` for using LINQ:

For example:

```
         (from x in Collection
         group x by n);
```

You can escape any C# `reserved` word by using the `@` symbol in front of it.